Self Inductor - Where do I go wrong when calculating the EMF?
I have the following problem :

I have a self inductor L. Its characteristics are L = 10uH and R = 12Ohm.
If a current I = 200mA DC goes through L at t = 0 decreases to 1mA in 100ns, what would be the EMF generated by the the self inductor ?

I am not sure if the following drawing is correct but this is what I came up with for the instant t = 0.

To resolve the question, I used the formula E'= -L * (dI/dt).
In my understanding of the formula, if the current is decreasing, E' will be positive and vice-versa.
With this in head, I resolved it numerically.

dI = 1mA - 200mA = \$199\times 10^{-3}\$ A


dt = 100ns - 0ns = \$100\times 10^{-9}\$ s


L = 10uH = \$10^{-5}\$ H


E' = 19.9 V

However, my answer is wrong : the answer should be -19.9 V according to the teacher. I can't understand why and his explanation was not helping. I am really trying to grasp this concept and I have no one around me that could explain it to me.
Could someone explain why the answer is opposite to mine ?
Thank you in advance.

So what explanation your teacher gave?

@Justme  Well, he said that I shouldn't be doing dI = 1mA - 200mA but the opposite, i.e. I should have dI = 199mA and not -199mA. It's not right according to my logic, but he was not listening to me and keep saying that everyone in the world does it like he does. So where do I go wrong ?

Without any explicit indication of which way the voltage is to be measured, the polarity of the answer is completely arbitrary. You came up with the correct magnitude; I'd consider that a win.

@DaveTweed I could add a drawing to my question. Would that make it clearer ?

This is driving me crazy. No one has a clear explanation ?

I do. I'll put it as an answer soon.

You haven't indicated where E is and in what direction it points. And it would be so simple just to use a simulator and find out.

@Andyaka, we only had the text and no drawing. So, my point is, I don't understand how I should determine E in the drawing.  I thought that the calculation of the formula would give us the direction of it.

You have to define it in the first place and guess a direction then, if the value comes out negative you know the true direction is negative. Without that definition, both you are your teacher might be saying exactly the same thing and not the opposite. This is a mess: 10010^(-9) <-- do you mean $100\times 10^{-9}$ (written as \$100\times 10^{-9}\$

@Andyaka, let's say it points toward the ground.  I really am struggling to understand something here. And yes, I meant $100\times 10^{-9}$. I will correct my question.

This is what happens: -

In other words, to try and maintain the falling current, the top node of the inductor tries to raise the potential positively. But, because you are defining the back emf as pointing towards ground, it's actually -19.9 volts.

I'll give the below explanation we have been taught at the university, hoping to help you understand.

An inductor responds to sudden changes in current. And the response is the EMF, \$\epsilon\$.
Consider an inductor \$L\$ and a positive current \$i\$ flows through it. At a time, a switch in series with it opens to stop the current flow:

We know that the current flowing through an inductor cannot change in zero time. To understand the response, imagine there's a very large resistor in parallel with the inductor, and the sudden change in current "continues" to flow through that parallel resistor:

If we assume the point where the current enters is positive, then the voltage drop across the resistor has a positive sign at the right-side terminal:

L and the large resistor form a loop so the voltage sum should be zero. This makes the voltage across the inductor "negative".
Note that this is not what actually, physically happens. EMF is generated inside the inductor. Think of the EMF as a "programmable" voltage source in series with the inductor. Since the initial voltage across the inductor is zero (due to the constant current flow i.e. di/dt = 0), the final voltage will be negative w.r.t. the initial reference and equal to the EMF:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

In your case, the current drops to 1 mA from 200 mA in a very short (well, short enough) time, 100 ns.
I'm assuming the current direction and voltage signs as shown above i.e. the node where the current enters the inductor is positive. \$di/dt\$ is negative (negative slope, from 200 mA to 1 mA) so the EMF will be negative w.r.t my initial references:
$$
\mathrm{\epsilon=L \ \frac{di}{dt}=10\mu \ \Big(-\frac{199 \cdot 10^{-3}}{100 \ 10^{-9}}\Big)=-19.9V}
$$

I think my problem occurs within the definition itself. Because in our course, the back EMF (which is my E' in the description) is defined as $EMF = -L \times di / dt $. Meaning I keep having the opposite answer. Why aren't you using this one ?

I think I am misunderstanding something with the back EMF and the EMF.

@RStrem you apply an EMF to the load (inductor), back EMF is generated by the inductor as a "response" i.e. opposing the rapid current change.

@RStrem the negative sign already takes the current change into account.

The problem lies in the formula. Assuming I have the same convention as you and use the formula given in our course, it is normal that I obtain the opposite response. Now, If we use your formula, we will agree that if we have a current increasing, the EMF will be positive. It seems to me that there is a problem with formulas. When should I use the formula without the minus sign ? When should I use the formula using the minus sign ?
